# How to use multiple jquery at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to use three different scripts >> jquery-1.2.6.min.js , jquery-1.4.2.min.js and jquery-1.9.0.min.js

First one is needed for Navigation menu bar, second one is for bubble effect on home page and third one is for opening fancy box.

But after using first, rest two are not working. In rest two i have used no-conflict and it worked. But when used first one, nothing is working...Only Bubble effect (that is first one - 1.4.2.min.js ) is working.

All codes are as follows:

**For Bubble Effect:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jshome/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jshome/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            $('#nav > div').hover(
            function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.find('img').stop().animate({
                    'width'     :'210px',
                    'height'    :'210px',
                    'top'       :'-25px',
                    'left'      :'-25px',
                    'opacity'   :'1.0'
                },500,'easeOutBack',function(){
                    $(this).parent().find('ul').fadeIn(700);
                });

                $this.find('a:first,h2').addClass('active');
            },
            function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.find('ul').fadeOut(500);
                $this.find('img').stop().animate({
                    'width'     :'52px',
                    'height'    :'52px',
                    'top'       :'0px',
                    'left'      :'0px',
                    'opacity'   :'0.1'
                },5000,'easeOutBack');

                $this.find('a:first,h2').removeClass('active');
            }
        );
        });
    </script>
```

**For Navigation Menu Effect:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jsnav/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jsnav/jquery.bgpos.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 $(function(){

     $j('#b a')
         .css( {backgroundPosition: "0 0"} )
         .mouseover(function(){
            $j(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-150px 0)"}, {duration:500})
       })
         .mouseout(function(){
        $j(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-300px 0)"}, {duration:200, complete:function(){
            $j(this).css({backgroundPosition: "0 0"})
        }})
       })

  });
 </script>
```

**For Fancy Box:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.4"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();          

        $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open({
                href : 'test.html',
                type : 'iframe',
                padding : 5
            });
        });


    });
</script>
```

Out of above three scripts, 1.4.2 and 1.9.0 are added in `nav.php` and 1.2.6 is added in `index.php` page. `nav.php` is added in `index.php` with `include("nav.php")`

Comment: That's only going to cause you endless problems. jQuery 1.2.6 is *extremely* old and will very likely have many problems on modern browsers.

Comment: Have you read jQuery's article [Avoiding Conflicts with Other Libraries](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/), and checked out [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)?

Comment: "I need to use three different scripts" - I doubt that. There doesn't appear to be anything in your code that would cause you problems if you upgraded to one recent version of jQuery. And there's the migration plugin if you get stuck.

Comment: @Pointy Thanx for comment, but for that bubble effect which i want to achieve, it is needed...

Comment: @DrManishJoshi how do you *know* it is needed?  You should try to get all your scripts working with an up-to-date version of the libraries.

Comment: Oh my... You are forcing users to load yet another 100kb library for 'bubble effect'. For 'bubble effect'! http://i.imgur.com/L3J6n.jpg

Comment: @Pointy i tried it using without that library, but then it is not working...

Comment: "... it is not working" *How*?  What goes wrong? What errors are reported in the console?

Comment: @Pointy the bubble effect disppears....and navigation effect starts to work...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this?

```
<script  src="../jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var first= $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.4.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.2.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var second= $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated my code for bubble effect as follows and now everything is working.....

Thank you for your support.

**Updated code is :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        $(function() {
            $('#nav > div').hover(
            function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.find('img').stop().animate({
                    'width'     :'210px',
                    'height'    :'210px',
                    'top'       :'-25px',
                    'left'      :'-25px',
                    'opacity'   :'1.0'
                },500,'easeOutBack',function(){
                    $(this).parent().find('ul').fadeIn(700);
                });

                $this.find('a:first,h2').addClass('active');
            },
            function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.find('ul').fadeOut(500);
                $this.find('img').stop().animate({
                    'width'     :'52px',
                    'height'    :'52px',
                    'top'       :'0px',
                    'left'      :'0px',
                    'opacity'   :'0.1'
                },5000,'easeOutBack');

                $this.find('a:first,h2').removeClass('active');
            }
        );
        });
        });
    </script>
```

After using this code, bubble effect, navigation effect and Fancybox Opening is Working.

Answer (score -1):

Please search before asking a question, a Google search for 'multiple jquery libraries' gives many useful results.

Anyway, you can add an extra code to your pages(s) so the jQuery libraries don't conflict with each other:

```
<script>
var jq142 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

I believe this code must be placed before the first jQuery library is loaded. I advise you not to use two jQuery libraries on one page but if you must to the above answer may help you.

Comment: Thanx for answer. ...I laready searched for multiple jquery but i get results for two jquery libraries and which is already used by me for naviation and fancy box. but when i tried third, it is not working...i tried your solution, but it doen't work...

Comment: @DrManishJoshi Okay. Try to do what the poster above me did: `<script type="text/javascript">
var second= $.noConflict(true);
</script>` but then replace 'second' with 'third'.

Comment: Thank you for your nice support